# the_title() shows title of the first post instead of the page title?

Tags: loop, title

I'm occasionally facing this problem and not sure what causes it, any ideas?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="content" role="main">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

For a normal page the_title returns "Page title".

But for a blog (using loop.php as in index file above) it returns "First posts title".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) is a Loop tag. It "Displays or returns the title of the current post" and it is supposed to be used *inside* the Loop, not outside of it.

What you are doing-- calling it outside the Loop-- is not quite correct, and you are getting inconsistent results. What happens is this:

1. The `$post` variable gets set to the first post in the Loop very early in the page load. For some pages, like single posts pages which have only one post in the Loop, that means `$post` is "the page you are on"-- more or less. For archive pages it is the first page in the Loop. You can put `var_dump($post);` before `wp_head` runs and see that the variable is already set.
2. Tags like `the_title` use that global `$post` variable. You have to trace it through a couple of functions to get there but eventually you get to the `get_post` function and you can [see in the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post.php#L386) that this is the case. In this case the chain is `the_title`->`get_the_title`->`get_post`

So, what you are describing is exactly what should be happening. You are using the tag incorrectly. It sometimes works the way you want only because of a quirk of the code. It isn't really supposed to work that way, or so it seems to me.

If you want "the page you are on" you will sometimes need to use [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object), but watch it since it returns different kinds of data depending on the page, and for some pages returns `NULL`. In other cases you are better off using the [`is_home`, `is_category`,  etc. conditionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) than you are depending on the query data like that. In fact, in most cases you are better off with those conditionals, or just with a call to [`wp_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) as toscho suggests, but the context you are trying to use this in makes me wonder if that is correct. Plus, the output of `wp_title` can be, and frequently is, manipulated by plugins (SEO plugins for example), which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 6):

On archive pages – blog, year, category and so on – use `wp_title()` to get the page title. `the_title()` relies on data of a single post.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. In a pinch, this fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was really confused why $post on the woocommerce shop page (that uses archive-product.php) was pointing to the first shop item. I assumed the $post would point to the shop page itself (as I needed to fetch some custom fields from the same)

Answer (score 1):

On archive pages – blog, year, category and so on – use `single_cat_title()`  to get the page title. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the same thing today, but I found a great solution:

```
  <?php 
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
      echo "Home";
    } else if (is_single()) { // POST, not needed for my site
      echo "";
    } else if (is_page()) { // PAGE
      echo get_the_title();
    } else if(is_category()) {
      $arr = get_the_category();
      if ( ! empty( $arr ) ) {
        echo esc_html( $arr[0]->name );   
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can help you is going to

```
WordPress Dashboard>Settings>Reading>Posts Page
```

Worked in my case.